# How to query keywords using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have some code that I am trying to figure out how to best query keywords and filter the data. I continually receive a syntax error or access violation. If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Here is the code that I am trying to get to work for querying keywords and sorting the data.

```
$whereSQL = $orderSQL = ''; 
if(!empty($_POST['keywords'])){     
    $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
    $whereSQL = "WHERE ad_city LIKE :keywords"; 
}else{
    $keywords = '';
}
if(!empty($_POST['sortBy']) && (strtoupper($_POST['sortBy']) == 'ASC' || strtoupper($_POST['sortBy']) == 'DESC')){ 
$sortBy = $_POST['sortBy'];
}else{ 
    $sortBy = 'DESC';
} 
$orderSQL = " ORDER BY ad_city $sortBy "; 

// Count all records 
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as rowNum FROM ads $whereSQL $orderSQL"); 
$query->bindValue(':keywords', '%' . $keywords . '%');
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch();
$rowCount = $row['rowNum']; 


// Initialize pagination class 
$paginationConfig = array( 
    'baseURL' => $baseURL, 
    'totalRows' => $rowCount, 
    'perPage' => $limit, 
    'currentPage' => $offset, 
    'contentDiv' => 'postContent', 
    'link_func' => 'searchFilter' 
); 
$pagination =  new Pagination($paginationConfig); 

// Fetch records based on the offset and limit 
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ads $whereSQL $orderSQL LIMIT $offset,$limit");
$query->bindValue(':keywords', '%' . $keywords . '%');
$query->execute();
$queryResult = $query->fetchAll();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use a placeholder for keywords like `ASC` and `DESC`, they can only be used where expressions are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use placeholders for values, you can't use them for table or column names, nor can you use them for keywords like `ASC` and `DESC`. You need to use normal string substitution for that. Use input validation to prevent SQL injection.

```
if(!empty($_POST['sortBy']) && (strtoupper($_POST['sortBy']) == 'ASC' || strtoupper($_POST['sortBy']) == 'DESC')){ 
    $sortBy = $_POST['sortBy'];
}else{ 
    $sortBy = 'DESC';
} 
$orderSQL = " ORDER BY ad_city $sortBy ";
```

Also, your query is guaranteed to return exactly 1 row. There's no need to check `$query->rowCount()` (it's always 1), or to loop over the results. Just fetch the first and only row.

```
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch();
$rowCount = $row['rowNum'];
```

Comment: Yes that worked for the sort option @Barmar, do you know why the keyword search seems to be tossing an error now?

Comment: Tossing this:  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':keywords ORDER BY ad_city desc LIMIT 0,18' at line 1'

Comment: The only way that would happen is if you tried to execute the query directly instead of using `prepare()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Barmar, the error was caused a few lines down at the next query. I added it to show what I have.

Comment: You need to use `prepare()`, not `query()`, just like the first query.

Comment: Haha, can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks again @Barmar. Much appreciated! Edited for clarity.